# Verify $ \frac {\cot x \cos x}{\cot x + \cos x} = \frac {\cot x - \cos x}{\cot x \cos x} $

Tags: trigonometry

Verify

$$
\frac {\cot x \cos x}{\cot x + \cos x} = \frac {\cot x - \cos x}{\cot x \cos x}
$$

Comment: $a/b=c/d$ is the same as $ad=bc$.

Comment: Are sure that this is true?

Comment: yes, that is what i mean by changing multiplication into subtraction. $$\cot^2 x \cos^2 x = cot^2 x - cos^2 x$$

Comment: @Sonnhard Looks true to me - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t0ab4ocaya

Comment: thanks, @Jam for the graph verification...

Comment: cross multiply ,cancel $\cos x $,again cross multiply   it simplifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by cross multiplication we get
$$\cos^2(x)(\cot^2(x)+1)=\cot^2(x)$$
from here we get
$$\sin^2(x)(\cot^2(x)+1)=1$$ this is true, since we get $$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$$

Comment: can you be more detailed? I don't see by cross multiplication we can get your answer.

Comment: @inyoot - multiply each side by the denominator of the other side, then expand all the brackets and try to simplify terms

Comment: $$ (\cot x \cos x) (\cot x \cos x) = (\cot x + \cos x) (\cot x - \cos x) $$
$$ (\cot^2 x \cos^2 x)  = (\cot^2 x - \cot x \cos x + \cos x \cot x - \cos^2 x) $$
$$(\cot^2 x \cos^2 x)  = (\cot^2 x - \cos^2 x)$$

Comment: The right side miss a minus sign

Comment: $$ \begin{align}
\cot^2 x \cos^2 x + \cos^2 x &= \cot^2 x \\
\cos^2 x (\cot^2 x +1) &= \cot^2 x \\
\cos^2 x \tan^2 x (\cot^2 x + 1)  &= 1\\
\sin^2 x (\cot^2 x + 1)  &= 1\\
\sin^2 x * \cot^2 x + \sin^2 x)  &= 1\\
(\cos^2 x  + \sin^2 x)  &= 1\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks @Dr.SonnhardGraubner ... I see it now...

Comment: Oh nice, one more problem is solved